# How to compare two decimal value in SQL Server without round-off?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
declare @a = 40.56
declare @b = 40.30

if(@a >= @b)
    select 1
else
    select 2
```

The comparison didn't work - help me?

Comment: Are you getting an error, or are you saying that it gave back the wrong value?

Answer (score 3):

You need to define the data type of the variables. Then you can set a value

```
declare @a decimal(8,2)
declare @b decimal(8,2)
set @a = 40.56
set @b = 40.30
```

Comment: Note that it is also significant that you are choosing to use `DECIMAL`, an exact type, when doing the comparisons.  Using `REAL`, an inexact type, might still result in an apparently failing comparison.

Comment: declare @a decimal(8,2)
declare @b decimal(8,2)
set @a = 40.56
set @b = 40.30   if(some condition) begin  if(@a => @b) begin  insert comment   end else begin return some statement  end  end else begin inserblock: insert statement end  but if the condition is failed then insertblock is executes!.

Comment: Please add the code you are talking about in your question in a formatted manner.